# Representation theory and the Nekrasov partition function

Tags: quantum-field-theory, resource-recommendations, supersymmetry, representation-theory, topological-field-theory

Is there any review or lecture notes on the [Nekrasov partition function](http://www.google.com/search?&as_epq=nekrasov+partition+function) which particularly thinks of this from a representation theorist's point of view?

---

Some possibly related references I know of are,

- H. Nakajima and K. Yoshioka, "Instanton counting on blowup. I. 4-dimensional pure gauge theory", [*Invent. Math.* **162**, 313–355 (2005)](https://doi.org/10.1007/s00222-005-0444-1), [arXiv:math/0306198](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0306198).
- H. Nakajima and K. Yoshioka, "Lectures on Instanton Counting", [arXiv:math/0311058](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0311058).
- Y. Tachikawa, *${\cal N}=2$ Supersymmetric Dynamics for Pedestrians*, [Springer, Cham, 2015](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-319-08822-8), [arXiv:1312.2684](http://arxiv.org/abs/1312.2684).
- (somewhere in this series?) J. Teschner (Ed.), "Exact results on ${\cal N}=2$ supersymmetric gauge theories", [arXiv:1412.7145](http://arxiv.org/abs/1412.7145).